# Creating lists of mutual neighbor elements

Tags: python, list

Say, I have a set of unique, discrete parameter values, stored in a variable 'para'.

```
para=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

Each element in this list has 'K' number of neighbors (given: each neighbor ϵ para).

EDIT: This 'K' is obviously not the same for each element.
And to clarify the **actual size** of my problem:  I need a neighborhood of close to **50-100 neighbors** on average, given that my para list is around **1000 elements** large.

**NOTE:** A *neighbor* of an element, is another possible 'element value' to which it can jump, by a single mutation.

```
neighbors_of_1 = [2,4,5,9] #contains all possible neighbors of 1 (i.e para[0])
```

> Question: How can I define ***each*** of the other element's
>   neighbors ***randomly*** from 'para', but, keeping in mind the *previously
>   assigned* neighbors/relations?

eg:

```
neighbors_of_5=[1,3,7,10] #contains all possible neighbors of 5 (i.e para[4])
```

**NOTE:** '1' has been assigned as a neighbor of '5', keeping the values of 'neighbors_of_1' in mind. They are 'mutual' neighbors.

I know the inefficient way of doing this would be, to keep looping through the previously assigned lists and check if the current state is a *neighbor of another state*, and if `True`, store the value of that state as one of the new neighbors.

Is there a cleaner/more pythonic way of doing this? (By maybe using the concept of linked-lists or any other method? Or are lists redundant?)

Comment: can you please elaborate on what is a neighbor of an element ? i did not get the single mutation thing.

Comment: By single mutation, I simply mean a random stimulus, that causes our current element value to jump to another value. It could be the effect of a random.randint() function. Sorry for the ambiguity!

Comment: I don't understand your problem exactly, but this sounds like a [directed graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) (or maybe [undirected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)#Undirected_graph)). Maybe it's useful to formulate it in terms of graph theory?

Comment: How many neighbors do you want (on average) for each element? How big is your problem? If it is only 10 elements, you could easily generate all possible permutations of two elements, filter them on the first being smaller than the second and then shuffle the results and pick the N first pairs as neighbors.

Comment: I basically want to generate a neighborhood for each element, keeping in mind the relationship between the nodes. @Thomas Thanks! I do believe graph theory might help me with this but just can't wrap my head around how it can be implemented.

Comment: @JohanL I need a neighborhood of close to 50-100 neighbors on average, given that my para list is around 1000 elements large.

Comment: @NishantGerald - let me know if my understanding is correct - you will generate neighbors of each element randomly (say 1 -> 2,4,5,7). Moving on for 5 when you'll generate neighbor list for 5 "randomly" - you must have 1 in its neighbor list bcoz 1 has 5. yeah ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution does what you want, I believe. It is not the most efficient, as it generates quite a bit of extra elements and data, but the run time was still short on my computer and I assume you won't run this repeatedly in a tight, inner loop?

```
import itertools as itools
import random

# Generating a random para variable:
#para=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
para = list(range(10000))
random.shuffle(para)
para = para[:1000]

# Generate all pais in para (in random order)
pairs = [(a,b) for a, b in itools.product(para, para) if a < b]
random.shuffle(pairs)

K = 50 # average number of neighbors
N = len(para)*K//2 # total connections

# Generating a neighbors dict, holding all the neighbors of an element
neighbors = dict()
for elem in para:
    neighbors[elem] = []

# append the neighbors to eachother
for pair in pairs[:N]:
    neighbors[pair[0]].append(pair[1])
    neighbors[pair[1]].append(pair[0])

# sort each neighbor list
for neighbor in neighbors.values():
    neighbor.sort()
```

I hope you understand my solution. Otherwise feel free to ask for a few pointers.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, and it runs quickly with my dataset as well! Also thanks for taking the time to provide explanations for each step! Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Neighborhood can be represented by a graph.  If `N` is a neighbor of `B` does not necessarily implies that `B` is a neighbor of `A`, it is *directed*.  Else it is *undirected*.  I'm guessing you want a undirected graph since you want to "keep in mind the relationship between the nodes".

Besides the obvious choice of using a third party library for graphs, you can solve your issue by using a set of edges between the graph vertices.  Edges can be represented by the pair of their two extremities. Since they are undirected, either you use a tuple `(A,B)`, such that `A < B` or you use a `frozenset((A,B))`.

Note there are considerations to take about what neighbor to randomly choose from when in the middle of the algorithm, like discouraging to pick nodes with a lot of neighbor to avoid to go over your limits.

Here is a pseudo-code of what I'd do.

```
edges = set()
arities = [ 0 for p in para ]
for i in range(len(para)):
   p = para[i]
   arity = arities[i]
   n = random.randrange(50, 100)
   k = n
   while k > 0:
       w = list(map(lambda x : 1/x, arities))
       #note: test what random scheme suits you best
       j = random.choices(para, weight = w )
       #note: I'm storing the vertices index in the edges rather than the nodes.
       #But if the nodes are unique, you could store the nodes.
       e = frozenset((i,j))
       if e not in edges:
           edges.add(e)
           #instead of arities, you could have a list of list of the neighbours.
           #arity[i] would be len(neighbors[i]), then
           arities[i] += 1
           arities[j] += 1
           k-=1
```

Comment: Thanks providing a solution with the graph POV! I understood most of what you did, which seems to be what I'm looking for. But, could you explain the use of the null-list _'arities'_  on which you're applying the lambda function?

Comment: The arity is just there to compute `w` for the `random.choice`.  Basically the less connection (low arity), the higher weight in `w`.  Maybe I shouldn't have included it as it clutters needlessly the code.